# Requests.get works locally but not on server(GoogleCloudRun/GoogleFunctions/GoogleColab)

Tags: web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-colaboratory, urllib

I'm trying to set up my script code into a server/virtual machine in order to run it every day. The scraping process works in Vscode and, locally, in a Flask API but it doesn't work in AppEngine, CloudFunctions, CloudRun nor G.Colaboratory.

```
url = "https://serviciosweb.mininter.gob.pe/visita/cargaconsulta.php"
fecha = 15/03/2022
querystring = {f"txtFecIni":"Wed Mar 16 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Perú)","txtFecFin":"Wed Mar 16 2022 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (hora estándar de Perú)","submitButton":"Submit","vtxtFecIni":{fecha},"vtxtFecFin":{fecha}}

headers = Headers().generate()

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
data = response.json()
```

The trackbacks are these ones:

```
In Cloud Platform:
    requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='serviciosweb.mininter.gob.pe', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /visita/cargaconsulta.php?txtFecIni=Wed+Mar+16+2022+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0500+%28hora+est%C3%A1ndar+de+Per%C3%BA%29&txtFecFin=Wed+Mar+16+2022+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0500+%28hora+est%C3%A1ndar+de+Per%C3%BA%29&submitButton=Submit&vtxtFecIni=15%2F03%2F2022&vtxtFecFin=15%2F03%2F2022 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x3e90695528e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))"


In GoogleColab:
    ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='serviciosweb.mininter.gob.pe', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /visita/cargaconsulta.php/?txtFecIni=Wed+Mar+16+2022+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0500+%28hora+est%C3%A1ndar+de+Per%C3%BA%29&txtFecFin=Wed+Mar+16+2022+00%3A00%3A00+GMT-0500+%28hora+est%C3%A1ndar+de+Per%C3%BA%29&submitButton=Submit&vtxtFecIni=15%2F03%2F2022&vtxtFecFin=15%2F03%2F2022 (Caused by <class 'TimeoutError'>: [Errno 110] Connection timed out)
```

Comment: servers may block some connections to stop bots/scripts/spamers/hackers and scrapers. They treats `scraping` as `stealing` and they don't want do this.

Comment: Is there any way to skip this blocking? In this case, I'm trying to scrape the logs of visits of Peruvian public entities.

Comment: I can't open this page even in local browser - so maybe it is only temporary problem with server serviciosweb.mininter.gob.pe . Or maybe it need connection from the same country - and this may need some proxy server.

Comment: @Fabrizio you might want to check this article to get some ideas on how you can [bypass the blocking in App Engine](https://juanluisrto.medium.com/scraping-google-search-without-getting-caught-e43bb91b363e).

Comment: Thanks, guys. I've already found the solution. As you both said, the problem was related with IPs. This web just receive Peruvian ips. I solved it with a list of Peruvian proxies.

Comment: @Fabrizio can you post your solution as an answer? That way the solution will be easily visible to the community.