# HTTPS Request Not Working in Google App Engine (Python Requests lib) / Cloud Shell

Tags: google-app-engine, curl, networking, python-requests, dns

I have been trying to do some html scraping for one of my projects, wherein the it is working from my local computer, but it is now working in google app engine. It is getting timed out.

I have tried using dig from google cloud shell, which is resolving the correct IP but still curl / trace is failing. Billing is enabled, haven't touched any DNS setting in GAE.

The target site is apparently using chunked reply.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, send_file, redirect, url_for, Response, send_from_directory
import flask
import requests
import bs4
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from urllib3.util.retry import Retry
import logging
import os

s = requests.Session()
r = s.get("https://kdseodb.smportkolkata.in/ccuPomsPosWeb/index.jsp")
id1 = r.cookies['JSESSIONID']
r2 = s.get("https://kdseodb.smportkolkata.in/ccuPomsPosWeb/apps/dos/PosCTS.xhtml")
id2 = r2.cookies['oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN']
headers = {'Accept': 'application/xml, text/xml, */*; q=0.01', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8', 'Faces-Request': 'partial/ajax', 'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty', 'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors', 'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36', 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Cookie': 'JSESSIONID='+id1+'; oam.Flash.RENDERMAP.TOKEN=-'+id2+''}

payload = 'javax.faces.partial.ajax=true&javax.faces.source=form1%3AbtnSearch&javax.faces.partial.execute=form1&javax.faces.partial.render=form1&form1%3AbtnSearch=form1%3AbtnSearch&form1%3AcomMloCd_focus=&form1%3AcomMloCd_input=NONE&form1%3AtxtCntNo=ABCD1234567&form1%3AtblData_scrollState=0%2C0&form1_SUBMIT=1&javax.faces.ViewState=PCsvYkkMUQAmP0zfu2tj7G5AqM%2BXrDH8%2BaG%2FROvEtWIHJyXX'

r3 = s.post("https://kdseodb.smportkolkata.in/ccuPomsPosWeb/apps/dos/PosCTS.xhtml", cookies=r.cookies, headers=headers, data=payload)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r3.text)
```

dig output from google cloud shell, **NXDOMAIN** is coming up when used on the IPs

```
dig kdseodb.smportkolkata.in

; <<>> DiG 9.16.33-Debian <<>> kdseodb.smportkolkata.in
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 414
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;kdseodb.smportkolkata.in.      IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
kdseodb.smportkolkata.in. 3600  IN      A       117.242.152.158
kdseodb.smportkolkata.in. 3600  IN      A       203.153.37.38

;; Query time: 6 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 29 01:44:36 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 85


dig 117.242.152.158

; <<>> DiG 9.16.33-Debian <<>> 117.242.152.158
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 29831
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;117.242.152.158.               IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       86400   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2022122801 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 5 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 29 01:45:39 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 119


dig 203.153.37.38

; <<>> DiG 9.16.33-Debian <<>> 203.153.37.38
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 32307
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;203.153.37.38.                 IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       86400   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2022122801 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254)
;; WHEN: Thu Dec 29 01:46:13 UTC 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117
```

Comment: you can check this article  on how you can [bypass the blocking in App Engine](https://juanluisrto.medium.com/scraping-google-search-without-getting-caught-e43bb91b363e) as also mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71503810/requests-get-works-locally-but-not-on-servergooglecloudrun-googlefunctions-goog)

Comment: Instead of trying to get the server to work on google, I was able to run the server in android device using Termux and solve my problem (albeit with ~ 1 gb extra space usage) and everything worked well!